# how to create new controller and model in Refinerycms and how use it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2, refinerycms

here, I want to create a application using refinery for that I need one new table resto. and to access that table I want to use my own controller resto. 
  how it is possible ? **please help me....**

Comment: Have you tried reading the RefineryCMS documentation?

Comment: yes... but there is not any concept like this...

Comment: http://refinerycms.com/guides/getting-started#extending-refinery-with-your-first-engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @sevenseacat mentioned, that refinery guide has a basic walkthrough of extending refinirycms.  Also if you haven't looked there already, [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com) has a [2-episode series on refinerycms](http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=refinery).  The second one deals with the subject you want but is a pro episode and you'd need to subscribe, but if you're doing any work with rails the pro subscription ($9/month) pays for itself very quickly.
Note: I am not affiliated with Railscasts in any way.